# Regex Negative lookbehind in React app breaking app on iOS devices

Tags: reactjs, regex

After a recent build my app has stopped displaying on iOS devices (just shows a blank screen).

After a log of digging, I've been able to narrow down the cause and it's this regex expression:

`(?<!@)`

Here's a context how I used it:

`/\b(?<!@)gmail\b|\b(?<!@)google\b/i`

which means I want to capture the words "gmail" and "google", but only if they are not preceded by an "@" symbol.

My question is, what is the correct regex expression that will do the same job, and work on all browsers/devices?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You could capture the words "gmail" and "google", but only if they are not preceded by an "@" symbol by matching them using a non capture group `@(?:gmail|google)`

Use an alternation `|` and a capture group `(gmail|google)` for google or gmail.

```
@(?:gmail|google)\b|\b(gmail|google)\b
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DjPCZ0/1)

For example, if you are doing a replacement you could check for the existence of group 1.

```js
const regex = /@(?:gmail|google)\b|\b(gmail|google)\b/g;
const str = `gmail
google
@gmail
@google
test@google.com
@agmail`;

let res = Array.from(str.matchAll(regex), m => m[1] ? `[REPLACED]${m[1]}[REPLACED]` : m[0]);
console.log(res)
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems close, but when I use it like this it only catches the words which are preceded with the @ symbol, not the other way around, how do I reverse it? This is what I did: `/@(?:gmail|google)\b|\b(gmail|google)\b/i`

Comment: @julia2019 I have added an example using the group in a replacement.

Answer (score 0):

You could just directly match a non `@` character:

```regex
/[^@](google|gmail)\b/i
```

If you need to also match the domain (which can only be `google` or `gmail`), then you may access the first capture group.

Comment: It only catches the last letter for me

Answer (score 0):

It seems that a combination of your two answers worked for me:

`/[^@](?:gmail|google)\b|\b(gmail|google)\b/i`

Thanks!

Comment: If so, then just use: `(?:\b|[^@])(?:gmail|google)\b`